# vba chart series dynamic axis multiple series

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a chart that draws in data from fixed ranges on multiple sheets. I would like the axis on these charts to automatically fit to the ranges, and to be focussed in on the meaningful range, rather than from zero.

If possible it would also be great to be able to get this from whole numbers.

I have written some code but I cant really get it to easily take the maximum value of each series, only the maximum of one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

[image: Sample]

Use the following VBA to adjust the y axis
(intentionally left the min / max functions referencing distinct ranges)

```
Sub Macro1()
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Int(WorksheetFunction.Min(ActiveSheet.Range("$B$2:$B$6,$C$2:$C$6,$D$2:$D$6,$E$2:$E$6")))
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Int(WorksheetFunction.Max(ActiveSheet.Range("$B$2:$B$6,$C$2:$C$6,$D$2:$D$6,$E$2:$E$6"))) + 1
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinorUnit = 1
End Sub
```

Hope this helps